# Baldur's Gate Enhanced Edition (OS X) and Dropbox

Tags: dropbox, games, symlink

I was trying to share the saved games of Baldur's Gate Enhanced Edition using Dropbox (on OS X). Configuration files are stored in

```
~/Library/Containers/com.beamdog.baldursgateenhancededition/Data/Documents/Baldur's Gate - Enhanced Edition
```

The options file `Baldur.ini` should not be shared as it contains machine specific data but I tried to make the `saves` folder a symbolic link to a Dropbox folder but then data is not recognised.

My workaround is to manually copy the folder to and from Dropbox after and before playing but I would like to know if someone found a better alternative.

**Edit**

The goal is to share the saved games between two machines using Dropbox (or another cloud storage server). Sharing the whole container is not an option as the settings file is machine specific.

As it seems that the question is not clear: How do I share Baldur's Gate saved games using Dropbox?

Comment: You might want to make it easier for people to actually answer your question by making it more clear what you are actually trying to do here and where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the sandbox. If you will look in your console you will see errors like: `...kernel[0]: Sandbox: Baldur's Gate...deny file-write-data .../Dropbox/Baldur's Gate - Enhanced Edition/Baldur.ini`

looking into how to allow this; I suspect that a hard link (instead of symbolic) would work. Best be sure you understand what that means before doing it.

Another way to do it would be to symlink the entire sandbox container for BGEE instead of linking a subpath. instead of a symbolic link for `~/Library/Containers/com.beamdog.baldursgateenhancededition/Data/Documents/Baldur's Gate - Enhanced Edition` make one for `` `~/Library/Containers/com.beamdog.baldursgateenhancededition ``

I haven't tested this with BG:EE, but I've done it with other sandboxes and it works.

Comment: You might be on to something here but could you elaborate on how the solutions would look like?

Comment: @patrix updated answer. also WTF with the downvote?

Comment: I can't comment on other users actions but somebody obviously considered the first version not being an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Can confirm that symlinking the whole container directory as Brad Allred suggested does work for BG2EE :-

```
mv ~/Library/Containers/com.beamdog.baldursgateIIenhancededition ~/Dropbox/com.beamdog.baldursgateIIenhancededition
ln -s ~/Dropbox/com.beamdog.baldursgateIIenhancededition ~/Library/Containers/com.beamdog.baldursgateIIenhancededition
```

Job done :)

Comment: Would you edit this into brad's answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can save files and folders in Dropbox even if they are outside the Dropbox folder. This is achieved with symbolic links in the Dropbox folder (you *must* use `ln -s`, for some reason Finder aliases don't work).

You could try something like this:

```
ln -s "~/Library/Containers/com.beamdog.baldursgateenhancededition/Data/Documents/Baldur's Gate - Enhanced Edition/saves" ~/Dropbox/baldur-saves
```

Make sure to backup your game data before doing anything.

Answer (score -1):

I've tried the same think for BG2:EE on OS X (mavericks), but failed as well.

First I moved the `save` folder to my dropbox folder:

```
mv ~/Library/Containers/com.beamdog.baldursgateIIenhancededition/Data/Documents/Baldur\'s\ Gate\ II\ -\ Enhanced\ Edition/save ~/Dropbox/save
```

Then created a symbolic link from the original save location to the new dropbox location:

```
ln -s ~/Dropbox/save ~/Library/Containers/com.beamdog.baldursgateIIenhancededition/Data/Documents/Baldur\'s\ Gate\ II\ -\ Enhanced\ Edition/save
```

But indeed the game does not find/recognize the saved games :(

Comment: this isn't an answer...

Comment: It is an answer, it's not a solution.
Besides that the OP didn't ask a question so please..